# When is the FAIR accelerator supposed to be finished?

Tags: soft-question, antimatter, accelerator-physics

The [FAIR accelerator](http://www.fair-center.eu/public/what-is-fair/accelerators.html) is a planned facility for antiproton and ion research.

Ground water wells are being put in, the forest is being cleared... But when is it supposed to be completed? Does anyone know?

Comment: No idea, but if I was to guess I'd say the if they are scheduled to continue site preperation for the rest of 2012 (guess the site is a out of date), then allow a year or more for civil construction, a year or more to install the infrastructure (shops, accelerators, cryofacility, power, computing, beauracracy, user offices, ...) and the first few detectors. Likely there won't be beam until 2015 or later. Wouldn't be too surprised if it was 2017. Particle physics can take a long, long time. Reading the design reports for the experiments might give you some idea of what the users are expecting.

Comment: Such questions are better suited for [chat] :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is amazing how unhelpful the site of FAIR is. No timelines or progress in time reports on main pages. The declaration of the director was in 2010 and no updates.

I found an estimate in [News](http://www.nuklearforum.ch/de/aktuell/e-bulletin/weg-frei-fuer-grossforschungsanlage-fair), n German. Fortunately my ruddimentary knowledge of the language helped me to see that there exists a time estimate. Also fortunately Chrome has a translate facility:

> 7-11-2012

.....

> The construction period will  be a good six years.

So there is your answer in black and white ( in German) and @dmckee justified in his estimate.